# Cordova Windows 10 Universal app - how to load external javascript file?

Tags: visual-studio, google-maps, extjs, hybrid-mobile-app, windows-10-universal

Windows 10 app is not able to load External Sources.

Example:

```
<script src="src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxx""></script>
```

Below are permission provided (cordova project)

Meta Tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; media-src *">
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

Comment: This question is not clear and the permissions you mention are missing. consider refining it

Comment: @Rob Thanks for quick reply, i have updated the question again. please revert for more information

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. Following url below fixed the problem. Windows apps only allow external resources in local context.

```
<iframe src="ms-appx-web:///x.html"></iframe>
```

http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/

Answer (score -1):

From Cordova 4.0 on domain whitelisting had to be done with the whitelist plugin
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md

Comment: The whitelist is android only as you can see in your own referenced file.